# REGEX in mysql query

Tags: mysql

i have a table with `address` as column.

values for address is `"#12-3/98 avenue street"`, which has numbers, special characters and alphabets.

i want to write my sql query usng `regex` to *remove special characters* from the address value

ex: "`12398avenuestreet`" will be the value i want after removing the special characters

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this [function](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?118,229993,240768#msg-240768) help you

```
CREATE FUNCTION strip_non_alpha(
_dirty_string varchar(40)
)
RETURNS varchar(40)
BEGIN
DECLARE _length int;
DECLARE _position int;
DECLARE _current_char varchar(1);
DECLARE _clean_string varchar(40);

SET _clean_string = '';
SET _length = LENGTH(_dirty_string);
SET _position = 1;
WHILE _position <= _length DO
SET _current_char = SUBSTRING(_dirty_string, _position, 1);

IF _current_char REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]' THEN
SET _clean_string = CONCAT(_clean_string, _current_char);
END IF;

SET _position = _position + 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN CONCAT('', _clean_string);
END;
```

so you need to call this like

```
update mytable set address = strip_non_alpha(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RegExp for simple character replacement.

[MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL regular expressions are "match only", you cannot do a replace in your query. This leaves you with only something like this (witch is very-very stupid):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '?', ''), '#', '') -- and many many other nested replaces
FROM table
```

Or put this logic inside your application (the best option here).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL regular expressions is only for pattern matching and not replacing, so your best bet is to [create a function](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?118,229993,240768#msg-240768) or a repetative use of [Replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: could you please breif about how do i do it by creating a function

Comment: You have the link in my answer, it's the full function declaration.

Comment: can i use this regex "[A-Za-z 0-9]" to check for alphabets and numbers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to replace via [MySQL regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), since these functions are only used for matching.

Alternatively, you can use [MySQL Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) for this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(address, '#', ''), '-', ''), '/', ''), ' ', '') FROM table;
```

Which will remove `#`, `-`, `/` and spaces and result in the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/) MySQL UDF. And then simply,

```
update my_table set my_column = PREG_REPLACE('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/' , '' , my_column);
```